# Accessing members of a class QList Pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qlist

I have this project where I use a `QList` to store instances of a class called `RespirationTest`. Accessing `RespirationTest` members is easy when using dynamic memory, but I am having trouble since I switched my `QList` for a pointer

```
//class declaration

class RespirationTest: public QListWidgetItem
{

public:
    RespirationTest();
    ~RespirationTest();

public slots:
double GetAmplitude() { return _amplitude; }

private:
double _amplitude;
}
```

Problem is here, when I try to access members of my `QList` objects (used to work when `respTest` was a `QList`)

```
//MainWindow

QList<RespirationTest> * respTests;

respTests = new QList<RespirationTest>;

void MainWindow::on_load_button_clicked()
{
RespirationTest *currTest = new RespirationTest;
respTests->push_back(*currTest);
qDebug() << "ampl" << i << ": " << respTests[i].GetAmplitude(); // no member named 'GetAmplitude'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** Use `.at(int idx)` instead:

```
qDebug() << "ampl" << i << ": " << respTests->at(i).GetAmplitude();
```

The problem with using `operator[]` is that you access the memory of the pointer instead of accessing the underlying `QList`:

```
respTests[i] // returns the QList<> instance at `i` instead
             // of a `RespirationTest` object
```

So if you want to keep using `[]`, you will need to further access the `i`th element by using `[]` or `.at()`:

```
qDebug() << "ampl" << i << ": " << respTests[0].at(i).GetAmplitude();
```

I highly recommend using `.at()` if you *really* have to do this. Otherwise just don't use pointers at all as it's over-complicating the problem and may leak memory. Furthermore, avoid `QList<>`, use `QVector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

since `respTests` is a pointer you need to use `->` instead of `.`

```
qDebug() << "object at " << i << ": " << respTests->at(i).GetAmplitude();
```

Comment: `respTests[0]->at(i)` will not compile.

Comment: @Waqar Hi dude!! thanks a lot!!!!, my fault but now is edited and tested...